# Vi Editor : Insert Line feed above a pattern with same count of white spaces

Tags: regex, vim, vi

```
if (BT_IS_SUCCESS(xCode))
        {                
          if (!(BT_IS_SUCCESS(xCode)))
          {
             else
           {
             if ()
             {

             }
           }
          }
        }
```

I m trying to insert a newline before every if - statement in an intended code base.
whenever i insert newline using \r the white spaces are not retained.

I m currently using

```
:1,$ g/;\nif (


:%s//;\r\rif
```

Here new-lines are inserted but to retain same number of white spaces what options are available .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

does this help?

```
:g/if (/normal O
```

Comment: @romainl I just noticed that I am the first, I thought you were 29sec faster than me when I saw your comment.... well, you have pasted example codes...

Comment: Thanks for the reply.what is the command to add same newline(using norm O) some n line above current search. for eg:  line no : 88 if ( , i need to insert a statement n line above if(

Answer (score 1):

If you want to turn this:

```
function dummy() {
  if (true) {
    return true;
  else {
    return false;
  }
  if (true) {
    return true;
  else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

into that:

```
function dummy() {

  if (true) {
    return true;
  else {
    return false;
  }

  if (true) {
    return true;
  else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

one solution is to do:

```
:g/if (/norm! O
```

or you could do:

```
:g/if (/put!=''
```

Comment: `put!=''` -> `put!` -> `pu!` well, if `"` is empty...  I am picky, aren't I? :) +1 for 29sec!!

Comment: `pu!_` because nothing comes out of the black hole register